# Counting unique values in rows and columns in MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I currently have a table that looks like the following:

```
[BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID]   [Error Type 1]    [Error Type 2]     [Error Type 3]
```

> ```
>      PVT02                  108                                  93
>      PVT02                   98   
>      PVT02                   80              80                  80
>      PVT02                   80              
>      PVT02                   93   
>      PVT02                   27              80
>      PVT03                   21   
>      PVT03                   102  
>      PVT03                   80   
>      PVT03                   80                                  102
>      PVT03                   80   
>      PVT03                   80   
>      PVT03                   71
> ```

Based on each Business_Process_Id, i'm looking to write a query that counts each unique error type. Ie. the query output should look like the following:

```
[BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID]    [Error Type]  [Count of Unique Error Types Combined]
```

> ```
>      PVT02                  108                     1
>      PVT02                   98                     1
>      PVT02                   80                     5
>      PVT02                   93                     2
>      PVT02                   27                     1
>      PVT02                   98                     1
>      PVT03                   21                     1
>      PVT03                   102                    2
>      PVT03                   80                     4
>      PVT03                   71                     1
> ```

As you can see, I'm not concerned with whether or not the count is by Error Type 1, 2 or 3. I'm looking to get the count of UNIQUE Error Types (ie. 98,80,108 etc.) by Business_Process_ID.

Could someone help? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a UNION query to first put all error types into a single column. Then, you can use a simple query to aggregate the results into how you wish to see them.

```
SELECT BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID, [Error Type 1] as ErrorType
FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID, [Error Type 2] as ErrorType
FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID, [Error Type 3] as ErrorType
FROM TableName
```

Save this as a query.

Then, use this query in a aggregation query similar to the following:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID, ErrorType, Count(ErrorType) as Number_Of_Errors
FROM MyUnionQuery
GROUP BY BUSINESS_PROCESS_ID, ErrorType
```

Comment: @HansUp Good point. Edited to use `UNION ALL` instead of UNION.